# BootStrap.groovy causing grails to fail

Tags: grails, groovy, bootstrapping

migrating old 2.2.2 app to 3.1.2, can i know why this app is crashing because of bootstrap.groovy
any help will be appreciated thank you

using: grails 3.1.2, mysql workbench 6

This is the Bootstrap.groovy to which causes the whole application to stop running

```
import grailsapp.Location;
import grailsapp.State;
import grailsapp.User;
import grailsapp.Type;

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        new State(state: "Issuable", updates: [:]).save(failOnError:true)
        new State(state: "Holding", updates: [:]).save(failOnError:true)
        new State(state: "In for repair", updates: [:]).save(failOnError:true)

        new Location(location: "L163", specific: "Rack 3A", updates: [:]).save(failOnError:true)
        new Location(location: "L163", specific: "Rack 3B", updates: [:]).save(failOnError:true)
        new Location(location: "L163", specific: "Rack 3C", updates: [:]).save(failOnError:true)

        new User(username:"blah", password: User.hashPassword("password"), firstName:"blah", lastName:"blah", isAdmin:true, updates:[:]).save(failOnError:true)

        new Type(type:"Dell E6500").save(failOnError:true)
        new Type(type:"Dell E6510").save(failOnError:true)
        new Type(type:"Dell E6520").save(failOnError:true)

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

These are the errors in which it causes

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'grailsapp.State' on field 'updates': rejected value [{}]; codes [grailsapp.State.updates.typeMi
smatch.error,grailsapp.State.updates.typeMismatch,state.updates.typeMismatch.error,state.updates.typeMismatch,typeMismat
ch.grailsapp.State.updates,typeMismatch.updates,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [updates]; default m
essage [Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Set()]

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8
.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075) ~
[springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77) ~[groovy-2.4.
6.jar:2.4.6]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1714) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1531) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeConstructorOf(InvokerHelper.java:954) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.
6]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.newInstance(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:15640) ~[groovy-2.4.6.
jar:2.4.6]
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:131) ~
[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:140) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-5.0.2.R
ELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at grailsapp.State.save(State.groovy) ~[main/:na]
        at grailsapp.State.save(State.groovy) ~[main/:na]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:10) ~[main/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloa
ded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) ~[groovy-2.4.6
.jar:2.4.6]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:437) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.1.2.jar:3
.1.2]
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:430) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:406) ~[grails-bootstrap-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2
]
        at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62) ~[g
rails-web-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65) ~[grails-
web-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53) ~[grail
s-plugin-controllers-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:24
0) ~[grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy) ~
[grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMult
icaster.java:163) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMult
icaster.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:3
81) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:3
35) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:
855) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationC
ontext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~
[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext
.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.ja
r:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-
1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.
3.2.RELEASE]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6
]
        at grailsapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

state.groovy

```
package grailsapp

class State {

    String state

    static hasMany = [updates: Update]

    static constraints = {
        state    blank:false
    }

    String toString() {
        state
    }

    static ArrayList<State> getStates() {
        State.findAllByStateNotEqual("Issued")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Grails 3.1.1 or 3.1.3. The 3.1.2 version has some bugs with validation.

Comment: flush your save.   *.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your State Class, I have checked that 'updates' field is a hasMany relationship. It says that the relation is from 0 to many objects. I mean, It is not obligatory to specify the updates, so if you write your state class without updates, it must be valid:

`new State(state: "Issuable")
 new State(state: "Holding")
 new State(state: "In for repair")`

Your problem now is that if you try:

`new State(state: "Issuable", updates: [:]).save(failOnError:true)   or
new State(state: "Issuable", updates: []).save(failOnError:true)`

you'll get an error because updates musn't be a map or a list. It must be an object of 'Update' class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `updates` field on `State` is a `Set` but you're initializing it with a `Map`.  Try:

```
new State(state: "Issuable", updates: []).save(failOnError:true)
new State(state: "Holding", updates: []).save(failOnError:true)
new State(state: "In for repair", updates: []).save(failOnError:true)
```

Comment: C:\dir\init\BootStrap.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class State
 @ line 6, column 3.
                new State(state: "Holding", updates: []).save(failOnError:true)
     ^

Comment: There is probably no good reason to be initializing `updates` before save anyway.